# Jquery toggleActive does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I dont really know how to code in Javascript. For an Airconsole I need to create the Controllers tho because it happens that I am the only one on our team able to use CSS and HTML.

Now I wanted to create a button that changes the color, as it was pressed (and stays that color)
Well I tried, but cant figure out how to get it to work. I hope you can help me.

My HTML :

```
<div id="characterScreen_readyButton" class="characterScreen_center" ontouchend="sendReady();" ontouchend="sendReady();">
    <div class="readyButton">           
    </div>
</div>
```

Here my CSS :

```
.readyButton{
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background: url("images/readyButton.png") no-repeat center;
            background-size: contain;

        }

.readyButton.active {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background: url("images/readyButtonP.png") no-repeat center;
            background-size: contain;
        }
```

And my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" >
$('.readyButton').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).removeClass('active')
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active')
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure that div with `readyButton` exists when you bind a click event handler to it either (1) bind after it appears in the HTML, or (2) make sure to bind [after the DOM is ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.readyButton').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot have a `<script src=` with script inside.
this will fix your problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" ></script>
<script>
$('.readyButton').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).removeClass('active')
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active')
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.toggleClass` instead of adding and removing  classes

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-
3.2.1.js" ></script>
<script>
$('.readyButton').click(function(){
 $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
</script>
```

Comment: How does this address the problem?  It still should work.

Comment: @Sablefoste the first problem was `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" >` this one, he didnt closed the script tag and wrote the function inside it

Answer (score 0):

Change Like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   //Other javascript
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

What is exactly problem? I think this code is good but probably your button is not visible (try change height for example to 100px).

Correct solution is above.